# Is it possible to install a program that puts assemblies into the GAC without administrator rights?

Tags: c#, .net, uac, gac

Do you need administrative rights to install an application that requires assemblies to be in the GAC?

The comment below in this post [What gacutil.exe should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889053/what-gacutil-exe-should-i-use) seems to say so:

> Also, users without administrative rights won't be able to install an application that requires assemblies to be in the GAC (like Oracle ODP.NET). In the case of ODP.NET, copy local doesn't work.

That seems to be the case here, and it makes sense to me, but I am looking for confirmation/clarification. Maybe I am taking it out of context for example.

I am thinking of the case where the installer is adding the assemblies to the GAC as part of the install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There is nothing special about GAC from Windows security point of view - it is just folder with files in the location that requires admin rights to change files.